# Can Indian Nationals get on arrival visitor visas in Saudi Arabia and Bahrain?

Tags: indian-citizens, visas-on-arrival, saudi-arabia, bahrain

I am an Indian national, and my family holds USA Visas on their passports. Can we get on arrival visitor visas in Saudi Arabia and Bahrain?

Comment: This is only a statement of fact (and it is true). What is your doubt?

Answer (score 3):

According to Timatic https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true

- Bahrain: YES. Nationals of India with a visa issued by USA, United Arab Emirates, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 2 weeks. They can apply to extend their stay for an additional 2 weeks.
- Saudi Arabia: YES, for applicants who have used their US, UK or Schengen visa for at least once, and who travel on one of the Saudi-based airlines. Repeat visitors who already hold Saudi visit visa can use any other airline. https://gulfnews.com/world/gulf/saudi/good-news-pakistanis-and-indians-can-now-get-saudi-visit-visa-on-arrival-and-can-also-perform-umrah-1.69897587

Comment: @Hanky Panky Thanks, answer updated.